# connect two different database in one laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to minimize  this by removing `if else` statement using simple code in laravel 5.5 can someone help me with it?

```
public function shirts($type='')
{
    if($type == 'glass') {
        $shirt = Product::where('category_id','1')->get();
        $products = Category::find(1);
    } elseif ($type == 'ic') {
        $shirt = Product::where('category_id','2')->get(); 
        $products = Category::find(2);
    } elseif ($type == 'cover') {
        $shirt = Product::where('category_id','3')->get();
        $products = Category::findOrFail(3);
    } else {
        $shirt = Product::all();
    }
    return view('front.shirt',compact('products','shirt'));
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: i would rather not handle it here simply send this function the category id for  which you want data..and somewhere else map categories with ids or have some function that would it for you..

Comment: You need to set the connections in the model. create a private $connection variable, then a method to set it and another to get it.  And then you will call those methods when needed in an if/else or switch. If you have not done so, you will need to update your config/database.php for the second connection, then add the second connection to your .env file

Comment: Check out this on setting up the multiple databases: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a mappings for your type and comparing the type with the mappings.

```
public function shirts($type = '')
{
    $type_mappings = [
        'glass' => 1,
        'ic'    => 2,
        'cover' => 3
    ];

    if(array_key_exists($type, $type_mappings)) {
        $shirt = Product::where('category_id', $type_mappings[$type])->get();
        $products = Category::find($type_mappings[$type]);
    } else {
        $shirt = Product::all();
        $products = null;
    }

    return view('front.shirt', compact('products', 'shirt'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** i assumed you want to avoid `if else` not as what the title of question says if still i am unclear please add comment so i can update the answer Thanks!

Lets handle it somewhere else as  i guess your function only has the responsibility to find product based on id it get not mapping part so we can have something like :

```
// Your function with single responsibility to return product.
public function shirts($category = '')
{
    $type = $this->CategoryIdMapper($category);

    if($type == 0) {
        $shirt = Product::all();
        $products = null;
    } else{
        $shirt = Product::where('category_id',$type_id)->get(); 
        $products = Category::findOrFail($type_id); 
    }
    return view('front.shirt',compact('products','shirt'));
}

//let the mapping part be done by some independent function which you can later modify accordingly and independently.
public function CategoryIdMapper($category)
{
   $categories = ['glass'=>1, 'ic'=> 2, 'cover' => 3 ];
   if(array_key_exist($category,$categories))
   {
      return $categories[$category];
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoters please dont be ashamed of adding comment for downvotes..so that it will help the answer from being getting improved.. thanks :D

Comment: excuse me sir, I was on the bus and miss clicked, if you edit it I will remove my downvote (actually I can't). I'm sorry.

Comment: @aaron0207 ok..but i am not getting this (actually I can't) does that mean something..?? and i did an edit after the downvote..also we are here to help someone nd not to play some vote game..

Comment: When I was trying to remove my downvote it said: "You last voted on this answer 3 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." that's why I said: "Actually I can't". Again, I'm sorry. Downvote remove, have a good day